# Google Drive PHP API: How do I get all files in a folder created by my app, placed there by the user or another app

Tags: php, google-drive-api

So Google Drive has a lot of security, which is a good thing. By default, my app can only get the files it has itself created on the user's drive. However, I also need to be able to retrieve all files placed by the user (or another app) in one of the folders that my app created.

Example:

- My app creates a folder called "Stuff"
- Now the user manually uploads a file called "test.txt" and places it in "Stuff".
- My app can't see this file, even though the app created the folder that the file is in. This is what I'd like to fix.

In addition, I have seen code on stackoverflow and other places which gives my app access to the user's ENTIRE google drive, but I'd like to avoid doing that. I only need access to the files created inside folders created by my app, not everything. Besides, the code that I found about this was all from 2012 or earlier and doesn't work anymore due to undocumented changes in the PHP API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file, then you cannot access those files created by user/other app unless user gives access to your application for the newly created files. But if you have this scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive , then you should have access to the newly created files without user sharing it

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be impossible. I was forced to give my app access to the user's entire drive. Here's the relevant code:

```
$client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE,
)));
```

If anyone has a better solution, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to open the newly uploaded file with your app in order that you have access to it. I had a similar problem and used a workaround described here: [Drive API for Android unable to access the file created by same App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327219/drive-api-for-android-unable-to-access-the-file-created-by-same-app)

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, because I need my app to be fully automatic (when necessary), without any user input.