# Google Drive Android API: cannot find file using query

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In my app I connect to Google Api:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(mGDriveCallback)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mGDriveCallback)
    .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Then in `onConnected` function of `mGDriveCallback` I make a query request:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder()
    .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "buffer.txt"))
    .build();
Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(mFindFileCallback);
```

And in `onResult` of `mFindFileCallback` I check the result:

```
if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Problem while retrieving files");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Results size: " + result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount());
    if (result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() > 0) {
        Metadata md = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(0);
        Log.i(TAG, "DriveId: " + md.getDriveId());
    } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "File not found");
    }
}
```

Now, even though I have personally uploaded "buffer.txt" on my drive, I receive empty result's metabuffer. So, the code shows "File not found" warning. The same happens if I am trying to find a folder. I tried replacing `Filters.eq` with `Filters.contains`, but without any success.

Any ideas what I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When you've created the file, have you set the title to "buffer.txt" explicitly?

Comment: I've uploaded the file, then I've tried renaming it - no success. I've created a folder - cannot get it either.

Comment: Was the file uploaded to drive by your App?
Or did you upload the file in some other way (e.g. Drive web interface, or the Drive android App)?

Comment: I've uploaded it from web interface.

Comment: That explains it. FILE scope will only give you access to the files created or accessed by the app.
See here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes.
DRIVE scope will let you access all the files, but it's not supported by the Android API, so might want to use the REST API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_app_with_id_appid_cannot_be_used_within_the_authenticated_users_domain) when you encountered `File not found` error means that user does not have read access to a file or the file does not exist.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "notFound",
"message": "File not found {fileId}"
}
],
"code": 404,
"message": "File not found: {fileId}"
}
}
```

**Suggested action**: Report to users that they do not have read access to the file or that the file does not exist. Tell them that they should ask the owner for permission to the file.

**Note**: Make sure that you provide the correct `access_token` when making the `GET` request for file metadata.

Here's a related SO ticket: [Drive API for Android unable to access the file created by same App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327219/drive-api-for-android-unable-to-access-the-file-created-by-same-app)

Comment: I am totally new to android and I am not sure I understand the connection of "File not found" with my error. Essentially, what I am trying to do is to get DriveId of a file based on it's name. This file was created by myself, and I access it from the app using my own google account. Yet, the query returns no files found. Do you suggest that from my app I do not have access to my own Gdrive files even though the authentication did not return any errors?