# Append to google drive file wihout user selection

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am trying to add code to my android app that gets information from the UI and appends to a file in google drive. I have gotten as far sign in and authorization, as well as querying the file by name. Most of the SO threads I have read are for the old API or REST API.

However, I want to open it in Read/Write, or Write Only mode. I have tried looking at the quickstart demos and the drive API, but none of them are helpful.

How can I get the driveId programatically? I have tried getting the ID from drive itself. Is there a way to build Metadata that gets the ID from the query?

If I use `openFile(DriveId.decodeFromString(actual_id).asDriveFile()`
I get the following error:

j`ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DriveId: **actual_id**`

Is getting the file ID from the sharing link wrong: **drive.google.com/open?id=some_id**

If so, how can I achieve this?

```
private String id = "1fuTq1Q6MHrchgW7sZImjvSfpAShHhsbx";
private DriveFile file = DriveId.decodeFromString(id).asDriveFile();



private void getFile() {
        Query q = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "HelloWorld.txt"))).build();
}

private void appendFile() {

    Task<DriveContents> openTask = getResourceClient().openFile(file, DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE);

    openTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
       DriveContents driveContents = task.getResult();
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = driveContents.getParcelFileDescriptor();
        long bytesToSkip = pfd.getStatSize();
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())) {
            // Skip to end of file
            while (bytesToSkip > 0) {
                long skipped = in.skip(bytesToSkip);
                bytesToSkip -= skipped;
            }
        }
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor())) {
            out.write("Hello world".getBytes());
        }
        // [START drive_android_commit_contents_with_metadata]
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setStarred(true)
                .setLastViewedByMeDate(new Date())
                .build();
        Task<Void> commitTask =
                getResourceClient().commitContents(driveContents, changeSet);
        // [END drive_android_commit_contents_with_metadata]
        return commitTask;
    })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    aVoid -> {
                        //showMessage(getString(R.string.content_updated));
                        Log.i("DRIVE", "Sucess");
                        finish();
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to update contents", e);
               // showMessage(getString(R.string.content_update_failed));
                finish();
    });
}
```

Also the file exists and the ID is valid.. Apparently
[image]

Comment: If you happen to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327219/drive-api-for-android-unable-to-access-the-file-created-by-same-app), it was pointed out that this is a limitation of the Drive API for android and they are switching to use Drive REST API.

Comment: So this "feature" isn't documented by Google, even though the API says it's possible?

Comment: Well within 30 minutes of tinkering, I was able to make a java REST app that grabs files and lists their name/ID. The code is way less dense and surprisingly makes more sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for the GDAA (Google Drive Android API), it should be possible to download a file based on its ID alone by using `asDriveFile()`.

To do that you need a query and then store the information in a `Task<MetadataBuffer>`, and then should be able to `files.get(0).asDriveFile()` in the method where you are attempting to download by `FileId`. But even when pulling the metadata and use the query method, you are greeted with `IllegalArgumentException invalid DriveId` (which IS THE SAME ID, so it was never invalid), But it STILL shows it as invalid. I got tired of wrestling with it and went to the REST API.

Things to note: **The file you are downloading MUST BE: Doc/Spreadsheet/Slides, photo or apps script.**
You can choose the type of file you want to export it as. Here is the "[truth table](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)" for compatibility.

From this example it is easy enough to write your data and re-upload it. **However**, these files have a special encoding so you can't write the data directly.

Depending on what you need to accomplish, you can use the [sheets api](https://www.baeldung.com/google-sheets-java-client) or
[apache poi](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi)

```
// Copyright 2018 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// [START drive_quickstart]
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    private static String fileId = "super_secret_string";
    private static final String OUTPUT = "super_secret_path";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE); //DONT USE THIS SCOPE IN PRODUCTION!
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
        //Download the file from it's known ID
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT);
        service.files().export(fileId, "text/plain").executeMediaAndDownloadTo(fos);
        //Append some data to the file
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(OUTPUT, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("Goodbye, World!");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.close();

    }
}
// [END drive_quickstart]
```